# Error when creating MySQL data source in Power BI Services using a Gateway

Tags: mysql, database, powerbi, gateway, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to connect my Power BI Services account to a MySQL server to access a database. I have successfully installed the Gateway to enable data access to the server. However, when attempting to create the data source in Power BI Services, I encounter the following error:

> Unable to update connection credentials. Unable to connect to the data source. The data source is unreachable, the connection timeout has expired, or the data source credentials are not valid. Please check the data source configuration and contact a data source administrator to resolve this issue.

I have verified that the credentials are correct, as I was able to establish the connection in my Power BI Desktop using the same credentials. I would like to know how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue, or if there are any specific considerations for entering the credentials, server, port, username, etc., when creating the data source in Power BI Services.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or advice on resolving this problem. Thank you in advance.